# C# Graphics DrawLine Deletion

Tags: c#, graphics

my drawings are deleted in the code I wrote. If "refresh" is not used, the drawing does not appear. Is there a mistake in my drawing? I don't understand
How can I draw a new line without erasing my lines ?

Here's the code

```
Pen pen;
        Point startXY;
        Point endXY;
        bool ismoving = false;
        
        string choice = "Line";
        public Form1(){
            InitializeComponent();}
        private void drawArea_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e){
            startXY = e.Location;
            ismoving = true;}
        private void drawArea_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e){
            if (ismoving == true){
                endXY = e.Location;
                drawArea.Refresh();}}
        private void drawArea_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e){
            endXY = e.Location;
            ismoving = false;}
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
            //Graphics graph = drawArea.CreateGraphics();
            //graph.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            pen = new Pen(Color.White,1);
            pen.StartCap = pen.EndCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.Round;}
        private void drawArea_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e){
            switch (choice){
                case "Line":{
                        e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, startXY, endXY);
                        break;}}}
```

Comment: Post the relevant code in your question, not as a picture or a link to an offsite location.

Comment: Sorry, I edited.

Comment: Two ways.  Keep a collection of lines drawn, and loop through that collection in the paint event (yes, it means redrawing every line) or draw on a bitmap surface and just draw the bitmap.  See [Drawing lines with GDI - Invalidate() / onPaint problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7444053/719186)

Comment: Never use `control.CreateGraphics`! Never try to cache a `Graphics` object! Either draw into a `Bitmap bmp` using a `Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)` or in the `Paint` event of a control, using the `e.Graphics` parameter..

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't

Comment: @TaW - you realize you need to create a `Graphics` object to draw to a bitmap. So _never_ is a strong word here. But hooking on the `Paint` event is the correct course of action.

Comment: How should I edit in code

Comment: The traditional way to do drawing is to `Invalidate` the region where you made a change.  after you finish getting your start and finish points, calculate a rectangle that includes those two points as corners (tricky if the two points are vertically or horizontally aligned).  Inflate the rectangle a bit and then `Invalidate` that rectangle.  That will cause your Paint routine to get called.

Comment: @Flydog57 I found `.Refresh()` to work better because it forces a redraw as soon as the information has changed, instead of waiting on windows to decide when the graphics need to be updated.

Comment: @JAlex thats my problem, when i use "refresh", lines deletion.

Comment: @JAl Hehe, right. It was about a Graphics object bound to a control only. - Invalidate is recommended; Refresh will often draw more than necessary and cause flicker. - Afaik it is not really necessary to limit the invalidated area as the system will do that quite efficiently.

Comment: Windows Forms is a thin wrapper around traditional Win32/User32/GDI32.  The way you write a graphical program in that world is to keep an in-memory representation (something like a `List<DrawObject>` (where `DrawObject` is an abstract base class that has subclasses for each type of thing you want to draw)).  Your Paint routine walks that list every time it's called. Your user input code (click, click, click) then invalidates the regions where there have been changes.  The Paint routine will only draw on invalidate regions. You could write responsive 16-bit apps for 386s this way

Comment: @YükselKürekçi - unrelated issue, but the formatting of the code makes it really difficult to figure out what is going on. Read up on the [C# Language Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions) to make it easier for everyone else.

Comment: @Flydog57 - ah, [`WinG`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinG) and its joys of dll hell with `wing.dll` and the terrible memory leaks it caused.

Comment: @JAlex: Never used WinG.  We were pure MFC/Win32/User32/GDI back all through the 90s.  I was working on something like Visio (very domain-specific though).  Getting smooth drag/drop working when you dragged a complex graph of graphics objects on 16-bit Windows was, I want to say "fun", but that's pushing it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs to know how to recreate the entire graphics window at any time, because windows may ask it to redraw at any time.

So you need to keep track of the things to be drawn in a list and use this list in the `Paint` event to render to the screen.

Below is an example code that does this. The result looks like this

[image: fig1]

```
public enum Tool
{
    Line,
    PolyLine,
    Circle,
}
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Point startXY;
    Point endXY;
    bool isMoving;
    Tool next;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Drawing = new List<IDrawObject>();
        this.isMoving = false;
        this.next = Tool.Line;
        this.drawArea.BackColor = Color.Black;
        this.drawArea.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    }

    public List<IDrawObject> Drawing { get; }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        drawArea.Resize += (s, ev) => drawArea.Refresh();
        drawArea.Paint += pictureBox1_Paint;
        drawArea.MouseDown += PictureBox1_MouseDown;
        drawArea.MouseMove += PictureBox1_MouseMove;
        drawArea.MouseUp += PictureBox1_MouseUp;
        this.KeyDown += (s, ev) =>
        {
            switch (ev.KeyCode)
            {
                case Keys.Space:
                    next = NextTool(next);
                    UpdateFormTitle();
                    break;
            }
        };

        UpdateFormTitle();
    }

    public void UpdateFormTitle()
    {
        this.Text = $"Draw Area. Tool={next}. Press [SPACE] to switch.";
    }

    private void PictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        isMoving = false;
        endXY = e.Location;

        Drawing.Add(NextDrawObject());
        drawArea.Invalidate();
    }

    private void PictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isMoving)
        {
            endXY = e.Location;
            drawArea.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    private void PictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        isMoving = true;
        startXY = e.Location;
    }

    protected void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        using (var pen = new Pen(Color.White, 1))
        {
            pen.EndCap = LineCap.Round;
            pen.StartCap = LineCap.Round;
            foreach (var item in Drawing)
            {
                item.Draw(e.Graphics, pen);
            }

            if (isMoving)
            {
                pen.Color = Color.SteelBlue;
                pen.DashStyle = DashStyle.Dash;
                NextDrawObject().Draw(e.Graphics, pen);
            }
        }
    }

    public static float Distance(Point from, Point to)
    {
        var dx = (float)(to.X-from.X);
        var dy = (float)(to.Y-from.Y);
        return (float)Math.Sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
    }

    public Tool NextTool(Tool current)
    {
        switch (current)
        {
            case Tool.Line:
                return Tool.Circle;
            case Tool.Circle:
                return Tool.Line;
            case Tool.PolyLine:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }

    public IDrawObject NextDrawObject()
    {
        switch (next)
        {
            case Tool.Line:
                return new Line(startXY, endXY);
            case Tool.PolyLine:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            case Tool.Circle:
                var radius = Distance(startXY, endXY);
                return new Circle(startXY, radius);
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
}

public interface IDrawObject
{
    void Draw(Graphics g, Pen pen);
}

public struct Line : IDrawObject
{
    public Line(PointF from, PointF to)
    {
        this.From=from;
        this.To=to;
    }

    public PointF From { get; }
    public PointF To { get; }

    public void Draw(Graphics g, Pen pen)
    {
        g.DrawLine(pen, From, To);
    }
}

public struct PolyLine : IDrawObject
{
    public PolyLine(params PointF[] nodes)
    {
        this.Nodes=nodes;
    }

    public PointF[] Nodes { get; }        

    public void Draw(Graphics g, Pen pen)
    {
        g.DrawLines(pen, Nodes);
    }
}

public struct Circle : IDrawObject
{
    public Circle(PointF center, float radius)
    {
        this.Center=center;
        this.Radius=radius;
    }

    public PointF Center { get; }
    public float Radius { get; }

    public void Draw(Graphics g, Pen pen)
    {
        g.DrawEllipse(pen, Center.X-Radius, Center.Y-Radius, 2*Radius, 2*Radius);
    }

}
```